# Формирование массива в цикле

Tags: php

В цикле формируется массив, к примеру:

```
$phones = [];
while(true) {
    ....
    //Здесь достаются номера из бд
    $phones[] = $number;
}
```

подскажите, как сделать, чтобы если номер уже есть в массиве, то нужно по ключу этого номера заменить значение. Значение должно быть массив, в котором указан текущий номер телефона и количество раз, сколько данный номер появился в цикле.
к примеру в массиве уже есть номер `$phones[10] == '1234567'`,
в текущей итерации номер также `'1234567'`, тогда значение массива с ключом 10 должно быть таким:

```
$phones[10]['1234567' => 2] // 2- это столько раз данный номер появился в цикле
```

Comment: То есть дубликаты должны подсчитываться в подмассив?

Comment: @Let's say Pie, да

Comment: кстати и желательно добавить ещё дополнительную информацию в данный подмассив, к примеру: `$phones[10]['1234567' => 2, 'href' => url]`

Comment: а вам что сделать то надо по итогу? выходные данные то какие нужные? эти номера итераций вообще существенны? мне кажется задачу тут можно решить и средствами пхп несколько проще, да и вообще, скорее всего чисто на стороне субд.

Comment: приведите пример входящих данных, которые вы получаете в итерациях массива. и пример результата.

Comment: @Let's say Pie, тут не из субд берутся данные, это я образно сказал. К примеру данные берутся из сериализованного массива

Comment: или можно, чтобы сразу в массив `$phones` данные добавлялись как подмассив: `$phones[] = ['1234567' => 2]`

Comment: хотелось-бы посмотреть и на эти два варианта решения, чтобы добавлялись и так `$phones[] = $number;` с возможностью добавить подмассив, и чтобы сразу добавлялся подмассив `$phones[] = ['1234567' => 2]`

Comment: посоветуйте, как правильно сделать. Наверно правильней будет, если ключ будет номер телефона, а значение массив с данными, такие как добликаты, и доп. информация?

Comment: @word, вам это нужно? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bfbbb1c850db5cb733fc5aba23b4f52688bfda12

Comment: @word, подходит, или нет?

Comment: ссылка не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
$arr = [1337, 1447, 4424, 1337, 555];
$arr = array_count_values($arr);

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $res[] = ($value > 1) ? [$key => $value] : $key; 
}

print_r($res);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1337] => 2
        )

    [1] => 1447
    [2] => 4424
    [3] => 555
)
```